# Why does GridBagLayout provide strange result?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, grid-layout, gridbaglayout

[image]

I want the various components to spread out and fill the entire window.

**Have you tried anything else?** Yes, I tried `GridLayout` but then the buttons look huge. I also tried `pack()` which made the window small instead. The window should be 750x750 :)

What I was trying is this:

These 4 buttons on the top as a thin strip

The scroll pane with `JPanels` inside which will contain all the video conversion tasks. This takes up the maximum space

A `JPanel` at the bottom containing a `JProgressBar` as a thin strip.

But something seems to have messed up somewhere. **Please help me solve this**

### SSCCE

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import com.explodingpixels.macwidgets.*;

public class HudTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HudWindow hud = new HudWindow("Window");
        hud.getJDialog().setSize(750, 750);
        hud.getJDialog().setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        hud.getJDialog().setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());


        JButton addVideo = HudWidgetFactory.createHudButton("Add New Video");
        JButton removeVideo = HudWidgetFactory.createHudButton("Remove Video");
        JButton startAll = HudWidgetFactory.createHudButton("Start All Tasks");
        JButton stopAll = HudWidgetFactory.createHudButton("Stop All Tasks");

        buttonPanel.add(addVideo);
        buttonPanel.add(startAll);
        buttonPanel.add(removeVideo);
        buttonPanel.add(stopAll);

        JPanel taskPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
        JScrollPane taskScrollPane = new JScrollPane(taskPanel);
        IAppWidgetFactory.makeIAppScrollPane(taskScrollPane);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            ColorPanel c = new ColorPanel();
            c.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750,100));
            taskPanel.add(c);
        }

        JPanel progressBarPanel = new JPanel();

        JComponent component = (JComponent) hud.getContentPane();
        component.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        Insets in = new Insets(2,2,2,2);

        gbc.insets = in;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridwidth = 10;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        component.add(buttonPanel,gbc);

        gbc.gridy += 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 17;
        component.add(taskScrollPane,gbc);

        gbc.gridy += 17;
        gbc.gridheight = 2;
        component.add(progressBarPanel,gbc);

        hud.getJDialog().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `com.explodingpixels.macwidgets.*;`  An SSCCE should have no external dependencies.  No 3rd party APIs.  :(  Can you show the problem with a standard `JComponent`?

Comment: :-) very nice, please where (this toolbar) can be sticked

Comment: @mKorbel The `buttonPanel` is supposed to be at the top. More like `BorderLayout.NORTH`

Comment: OR..... maybe I can change the layout managers I am using. individually `BorderLayout.SOMEWHERE` the top and bottom panels and let the scrollpane take the CENTER ? @AndrewThompson You are the swing expert here

Comment: *"You are the swing expert here"* Only one of many.  @mKorbel is another.  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ok I tried the `BorderLayout` proposal. Didnt Work

Comment: as I searching, there isn't pack(), or container has hardcoded Dimension

Comment: @mKorbel `setSize` right at the start, sir. The window **has to be** 750x750. I must arrange the components and their sizes to fit this constraint :)

Comment: be sure that he's (@AndrewThompson) on Swing board, I'm only another member of clean_up factory ... :-),

Comment: @mKorbel I am ready to change the LayoutManagers in use as long as it provides the desired result :)

Comment: BTW - See [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) (for tips on making *great* screenshots).  (Hint: crop!)

Comment: @Little Child I'm wouldn't be going this way, split logics to separate containers (JPanel) with the same or different LayoutManager, then this job will be easier as can ....

Comment: @mKorbel I have `buttonPanel` with 4 buttons in it, a `JScrollPane` in which I add 9 `JPanels` to represent dummy tasks and a `progressBarPanel` which is also a dummy. So there are separate containers :) just 3 containers, that is :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson maybe I have to set the sizes myself as I am not letting the LayoutManager do the task ? I know it is a bad practice to mess with the preferred dimensions.

Comment: then to use GridLayout for JButtons (see that every has the same size on the screen) and to override getPreferred(ScrollableViewport)Size for JPanel / JScrollPane

Comment: @mKorbel I used `Box`. Solved the problem to some extent.

Comment: @mKorbel Gimme a *yes* or *no* answer. **Manually setting the dimensions of components is a bad practice. Right?**

Comment: JComboBox, JTable, JScrollPane can't returns its PreferredSize internally and properly, if yes then is required to override this value, then doesn't matter if is there setPreferredSize or setPreferredScrollableViewportSize or setPrototypeDisplayValue or setPreferredSize, for rest of them is about bad practicies,

Comment: @mKorbel the `taskPanel` has dummy customized JPanels inside it for now. They also need to be specific sizes. In that case I should override the `getPreferredSize` for them too ?

Comment: yes since isn't difference betweens getPreferredSize and setPreferredSize (for Standard LayoutManagers) is better to use getPreferredSize()

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
gbc.weightx = 1;
gbc.weighty = 1;
gbc.fill = GridbagConstraints.BOTH
```

Comment: Please elaborate what `weightx` does. Does it set how much each `gridx` equals in pixels ?

Comment: if `weightx` is 1, then this particular component will horizontally occupy the full remaining width of its parent container. Why i say "remaining" is there may be some other components that share the same horizontal space. ofcourse, this requires `gbc.fill` to be set either to HORIZONTAL or BOTH.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply place three `JPanel`s on top of one `JPanel` with `BorderLayout` as `Layout Manager`, where the middle `JPanel` with all custom panels with their respective sizes can be accommodated inside a `JScrollPane`, as shown in the below example :

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: Gagandeep Bali
 * Date: 5/17/13
 * Time: 6:09 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class PlayerBase
{
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JPanel centerPanel;
    private CustomPanel[] colourPanel;
    private JPanel progressPanel;

    private JButton addVideoButton;
    private JButton removeVideoButton;
    private JButton startAllButton;
    private JButton stopAllButton;

    private JProgressBar progressBar;

    private Random random;

    public PlayerBase()
    {
        colourPanel = new CustomPanel[10];

        random = new Random();
    }

    private void displayGUI()
    {
        JFrame playerWindow = new JFrame("Player Window");
        playerWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        contentPane.setBorder(
                BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        buttonPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER, 5, 5));
        addVideoButton = new JButton("Add New Video");
        removeVideoButton = new JButton("Remove Video");
        startAllButton = new JButton("Start all tasks");
        stopAllButton = new JButton("Stop all tasks");

        buttonPanel.add(addVideoButton);
        buttonPanel.add(removeVideoButton);
        buttonPanel.add(startAllButton);
        buttonPanel.add(stopAllButton);

        contentPane.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane();
        centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 2, 2));
        for (int i = 0; i < colourPanel.length; i++)
        {
            colourPanel[i] = new CustomPanel(new Color(
                    random.nextInt(255), random.nextInt(255)
                    , random.nextInt(255)));
            centerPanel.add(colourPanel[i]);
        }
        scroller.setViewportView(centerPanel);

        contentPane.add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        progressPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        progressBar = new JProgressBar(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);
        progressPanel.add(progressBar);

        contentPane.add(progressPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        playerWindow.setContentPane(contentPane);
        playerWindow.pack();
        //playerWindow.setSize(750, 750);
        playerWindow.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        playerWindow.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new PlayerBase().displayGUI();
            }
        };
        EventQueue.invokeLater(runnable);
    }
}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel
{
    public CustomPanel(Color backGroundColour)
    {
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(backGroundColour);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return (new Dimension(750, 100));
    }
}
```

OUTPUT :

[image: PLAYERLAYOUT]

Comment: I can not use `pack()` because I need the window to be 750x750 exact

Comment: @LittleChild : You might be right, but at the same time, might be wrong. Consider this scenario, in which you really don't know, on what resolution, the user of your application, might work on. So in that situation, `pack()` will come in handy :-)

Comment: Yeah. I just saw the answer above yours about `gridweightx` and `gridweighty` and may be that will solve my problem

Comment: `gridweightx` and `gridweighty` are not meant to entertain such thingy. They are meant to represent the space available inside the container, for the respective component. And the size of the `Container(JPanel)`, in this case will depend on the components it has, and how much size they occupy inside the container`(Preferred Size)`. For example, if your window is of `100X100` and you placing two components inside it. One with `weightx = 0.3/weighty = 1.0/gridx = 0/gridy = 0` and other one with `weighty = 0.7/weighty = 1.0/gridx = 1/gridy = 0`, that means the former one will occupy `30% `of the

Comment: continued... : Container, in which it resides and the laater one will occupy `70 % (from left to right orientation)`